# Running a BLDC Ceiling Fan on an Off Grid DC System

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

first post here and I'll start by saying my electrical knowledge is limited at best.

So I'm building cabin/weekend house and attempting to run the entire house, at least for the time being, on DC.  There is no AC in the house at this time.

In my ignorance, I purchased DC ceiling fan with the assumption I could "hack into it" and run it on DC using a step up converter and maybe a PWM controller.  Well, I bit off more than I can chew...

After inspecting the fan control box and doing some research, I believe the fan has a BLDC motor.  I might be able to fumble my way through matching up an off-the-shelf ESC but the output from the control box seems odd.  I might be interpreting the output incorrectly but I can't find anything that would work.

So here's the info I have at this time:

Fan Control box (pic attached):
Remote control, 6 speeds with Forward, Reverse, and 4 timer settings
Input:    AC 120V/60Hz
Output:   170 Vdc, 42W Max.
Output Wires:  Three wires labeled "To Motor"
No light on fan
Motor only has three wires matching the colors of the control box output

My Questions:

My Plan A:  Bypass the control box and feed DC directly to the motor via a step up converter and ESC.  Is there an easy way to do this?  Does the motor really need 170vdc and only 42W?

My Plan B:  Use a localized square wave inverter module.  Would the square wave damage the fan control box?  If so, could the square wave be converted to sine so as not to damage the control box?

Any additional ideas how to make this work?

Additional Info:

I do not need a remote, 6 speeds, or timer function.  A couple speeds and reverse is all I need.
Zero or very low standby and parasitic drain desired, which is why I prefer not to add a whole house inverter.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: If you run the fan at a lower voltage it just won't have the torque, so won't be able to get up to high speed.

Answer (score 1):

### Meet RMS

So where is that "170 volt DC" coming from exactly?

Edison built out a lot of cities with 220VDC 3-wire: +110VDC, 0V, -110VDC.  (that's where our split-phase weirdness comes from, it was a tactic to reduce voltage drop on DC systems).

When AC came in, they tried to figure out an AC voltage that would cause DC bulbs to burn the same brightness.  The answer was, an AC waveform with a peak of `DC voltage x sqrt(2)` will average to the same overall power.  This is called RMS (Root Mean Square).

Since Edison's day we've bumped AC power to 120V. 120V x 1.4142136 gives us 170 volts peak.  And that's where that motor controller is getting 170VDC.
It is simply rectifying 120VAC and has a capacitor to glide over the peaks. And pulsed 170 VDC is a good fit for 120VAC motors (though this one is wired 3-phase delta).

Since it is rectifying, it doesn't care whether it gets AC, DC or pulsed DC, as long as the peaks are near 170V.

I suppose you could use a DC/DC converter to step up to ~170V, but you really want a fuse on the low voltage side of it. DC much above 50V is extremely destructive and uncontrollable (warning: [turn speakers way down! That's 600V doing that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThIbMnE71HU)).

Or you could use a COTS inverter to make 120VAC RMS, or an inverter to make 12/24VAC and then a transformer to step it up to 120VAC RMS.

### Keep vampire load down

I completely agree with your viewpoint of avoiding general "vampire load".

As such, whatever DC/DC or inverters you use to power the fan, should be switched with the fan, e.g. through the normal switch.  Be aware that if you are using low voltage DC bulbs in the fan, the light wiring must bypass the module, because the module won't know what to do with it.

Comment: So you're saying the best option is to use a small inverter module and feed the control box with a high frequency AC square wave instead of trying to bypass the control box?

Comment: It sounds like your options are: Run it on 170v dc using some kind of boost converter. Run it on 120VAC using a small inverter. Or try to run it at a voltage lower than 170V dc and see how well it works (like 50+, it probably won't work at 12). You will probably be able to use the built in controller.

Comment: @Pnof You are confused about what a "brushless DC motor" is.  It's not a motor you apply DC to and magic happens. That would be a brushed motor :)   Brushless DC means you get 3 raw wires and you are responsible for commutation, which you must do electronically by driving it with effectively a 3-phase VFD. So best to leave the factory control box.

Comment: I'm not confused, I know what a brushless DC motor is and I know how it's controlled, that's why in my original description mentions Electronic Speed Controllers (ESC).  This was originally posted in the electrical engineering page but the moderators in their infinite wisdom saw the words "ceiling fan" and migrated it here.

Comment: @pnof sorry, I was confused by your first line.  My feeling is "reverse engineer the least possible.  If that controller knows how to control that motor, then *we don't even need to care what kind of fan motor that is*".  That reduces the problem from "identifying the fan motor type and scratchbuilding a controller" to "get that controller 170V peak somehow".  The latter seems much more solvable. **I loathe undue complexity because that kills projects**. Get to win. *Then* refine.

Comment: No worries, sorry if my reply was curt, I was a little frustrated my question was migrated.  I agree with what you're saying, I was just hoping to find a solution that didn't essentially involve going from DC to AC then back to DC.  I've worked hard to make this house as efficient as possible, to the point where 2Kwh can last me two days.

Comment: @pnof The essential key is to *turn off the inverter/step-up when the fan isn't in use*, and size the inverter/step-up for minimum vampire load.   With that unit, pick your poison: make 120VAC or make 170V DC.  It's all semiconductor chopping.

Comment: By the way for refrigerators, here's a concept ripped from booster substations on trolley systems. Have a right-sized inverter spin up at intervals (top of every hour?) and run the inverter until "low current" (meaning cycle has finished). Then shut off the inverter and wait.

Comment: So you think feeding the control box with something like this:  [link](https://www.amazon.com/Voltage-Boost-Converter-Inverter-Transformer/dp/B07MMMNCQL/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=9jp21&pf_rd_p=29505bbf-38bd-47ef-8224-a5dd0cda2bae&pf_rd_r=G1VBRXWP9TXHJ6RAP5HT&pd_rd_r=52e192e4-7e5e-444f-b935-1bc972c82dff&pd_rd_wg=Uxara&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_atf_m)

Comment: @pnof sure, but more "right-sized" and definitely RU-Recognized.  Nothing that touches 120V should ever be bought on Amazon, it's all Alibaba-tier crud which is fine for hobby DC tinkering, but never AC mains.   I get stuff like that from mouser.com, and they'll have DC-DC converters also.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

The motor has only 3 wires, so it is a Hallless BLDC (brushless DC) motor. What is your system voltage? If it is 24V, you might consider substituting for the factory 115VAC controller a Hallless 24V motor controller from Amazon for under $20. It would be a gamble, but it might run the fan at lower speed than with the factory controller. How to hook up the three wires? Hook up the 3 wires to the controller in random order. The motor should spin one way or the other. If it spins backwards, swap any two of the three wires. If the controller doesn't come with a reverse switch, you could put a reversing DPDT switch between two of the three motor wires and the controller. Some of the controllers come with a potentiometer for speed control and others take a PWM 5V input. You may need to ramp up the speed slowly to get it to spin with the lower voltage.

TI makes a ceiling fan BLDC motor controller chip that takes 24VDC input. They also make a board, TIDA-00386, that has 115VAC input, rectifies it and converts it to 24VDC and then sends it to the chip. So there must be ceiling fans that use 24VDC instead of 170V, but I don't know how to tell which  manufacturers use this voltage. If you could find one, you might be able to cut traces on the PCB board and wire in the 24VDC directly.

Keep us posted. I have three 24VDC fans. Two of them have brush-type motors, and I have had to replace the motors in both of them. The third doesn't move much air and makes too much noise.